# Should I list a TypeScript package as dependencies when I just want it's typing? I'm building packages as well

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Suppose I want to use a package named `some-other-package` for its typing.

I want to use TypeScript `typeof` to extract it's typing like this

```
import someOtherPackage from "some-other-package";

export const myFunction = (param: typeof someOtherPackage) =>
  JSON.stringify(param);
```

And my package has an exported function called `myFunction` for people who `npm install` my package.

Now, should I list `some-other-package` as my package's `dependencies`?

If so, when people `npm install` my package, I think they will be misleading that my package **is actually** using those `js` code as well.

Is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do `import type` now, which I believe will only download the dependecy types while compiling. This will always erase when is not needed and therefore won't be downloaded on runtime

[More about that on typescript 3.8 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export)